# c# How to create new row if theirs no space on the first row

Tags: c#

Hello the code below works perfectly but i was wondering on how i could implement code that once The row of balls cant fit in the picture box in the first row it creates a new row below that row and so on.

```
{
            //calculate the number of rows
            int ballRows = HEIGHT / (SIZE + GAP);
            // sets the seed posion in the picturebox
            Rectangle recCircle = new Rectangle(LEFT, TOP,SIZE,SIZE);
            Graphics paper = pictureBoxBowl.CreateGraphics();
            Pen pen1 = new Pen(Color.Gray, 2);

            // variable for amount of balls
            int ballAmount = 0;
            try
            {
                //changes text value to interger
                ballAmount = int.Parse(textBoxNumSeeds.Text);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //tells user of error and clears and focuses the textbox
                MessageBox.Show("invalid numeric input try again");
                textBoxNumSeeds.Clear();
                textBoxNumSeeds.Focus();
                return;
            }
            //makes y position for the circle rows
            int yPos = TOP;
            int xPos = LEFT;

            //creates new row under previous row  
            for (int cols = 0; cols < ballAmount; cols++)
            {
                SolidBrush SeedColour = null;
                int randBallCol = rand.Next(40) + 1;
                //if random ball colour is between 1 - 100 then set to blue
                if (randBallCol >= 1 && randBallCol <= 100)
                {
                    SeedColour = new SolidBrush(Color.Gray);
                }




                //changes new circle location by changing y position and adding gap and radius to it
                recCircle.Location = new Point(xPos, yPos);
                //displays the circles based on recCircle dimensions
                paper.FillEllipse(SeedColour, recCircle);
                paper.DrawEllipse(pen1, recCircle);
                //updates the xposition of the columns
                xPos = xPos + SIZE + GAP;

            }
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: The question is quite unclear. Also: _Graphics paper = pictureBoxBowl.CreateGraphics();_ Almost always a mistake.  - There are basically three ways to get a `Graphics` object for drawing: 1.: control.CreateGraphics for __non-persistent__ drawing (like a rubberband selection rectangle) 2.: the `e.Graphics` parameter in a `Paint` event of a control to draw on the control's surface and 3.: Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` for drawing into a bitmap. - Sometime you also need control.CreateGraphics for measuring stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what platform you are using, but let's assume WinForms for simplicity.

You need to reset the `yPos` when the next ball x-Position will be outside the size of the `paper` rectangle.

something like this just below the line where you update the x position right at the bottom.

```
int xNext = xPos + SIZE + GAP;
if (xNext > e.ClipRectangle.Width)
{
  yPos = yPos + SIZE;
  xPos = 0;
}
```

However its better to use the `Paint` event.

I set up a small WinForms app and it looks like this.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int HEIGHT = 5;
        int SIZE = 10;
        int GAP = 2;
        int LEFT = 0;
        int TOP = 0;
        Rectangle _recCircle;
        int ballAmount = 0;
        Random _rand;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _recCircle = new Rectangle(LEFT, TOP, SIZE, SIZE);
            _rand = new Random(1);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //changes text value to interger
                ballAmount = int.Parse(textBoxNumSeeds.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //tells user of error and clears and focuses the textbox
                MessageBox.Show("invalid numeric input try again");
                textBoxNumSeeds.Clear();
                textBoxNumSeeds.Focus();
                return;
            }
            pictureBoxBowl.Invalidate();
        }

        private void pictureBoxBowl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //makes y position for the circle rows
            int yPos = TOP;
            int xPos = LEFT;
            int xNext = 0;
            //creates new row under previous row  
            for (int cols = 0; cols < ballAmount; cols++)
            {
                SolidBrush SeedColour = null;
                SeedColour = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(_rand.Next(255), _rand.Next(255), _rand.Next(255)));
                //changes new circle location by changing y position and adding gap and radius to it
                _recCircle.Location = new Point(xPos, yPos);
                //displays the circles based on recCircle dimensions
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(SeedColour, _recCircle);
                e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(SeedColour), _recCircle);
                //updates the xposition of the columns
                xPos = xPos + SIZE + GAP;

                //test if a new row is required
                xNext = xPos + SIZE + GAP;
                if (xNext > e.ClipRectangle.Width)
                {
                    yPos = yPos + SIZE;
                    xPos = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and gives you this result.

[image: balls on new rows]